# How can I allow element to draw outside of container, but still scroll with container?

Tags: css

I am working on a website with a sort of glow effect in the background of my banner. Ideally the glow effect would only show up at the top of my page, and when my user scrolls it would also scroll with the container.

My problem is that id also like these glow effects to show up on my header and behind my scrollbar. I can get that working by adjusting my glow-1 to glow-3 to be fixed position which gives me exactly how i want my design to look, but when i scroll my container those glow elements do not scroll with the container anymore which is not what i was looking for

I believe my issue is due to how using fixed position makes my glow elements "out of flow", but I'm not sure how else to achieve my desired results. Any alternative ideas to solve this? I have been working on this for 2 days now and am at a loss for how to make this work the way i want. Thank you!

Absolute positioned example that scrolls the glow effect with the container:
https://jsfiddle.net/ugoa7y5t/1/

```css
:root {
    --gradient: linear-gradient(to top left, #e65c00, #F9D423);

    --background: 25 65% 3.6%;
    --foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --muted: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --muted-foreground: 25 10% 54.5%;

    --popover: 25 57% 6.30%;
    --popover-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --card: 25 57% 6.31%;
    --card-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --border: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --input: 25 0% 17.55%;

    --primary: 25 100% 45%;
    --primary-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --secondary: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --secondary-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --accent: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --accent-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
    --destructive-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --ring: 25 100% 45%;
  }

html,
body,
#root,
.app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans 3', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(var(--background));
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.css-ohwg9z {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.css-4tfloy-MuiPaper-root-MuiAppBar-root {
    background-color: hsla(25, 57%, 6.31%, 1);
    color: hsla(25, 10%, 97.25%, 1);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1100;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.css-1oqqzyl-MuiContainer-root {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .css-1oqqzyl-MuiContainer-root {
      padding-left: 24px;
      padding-right: 24px;
  }
}
.css-r6ewbb-MuiToolbar-root {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 56px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px){
  .css-r6ewbb-MuiToolbar-root {
      min-height: 64px;
  }
}

.css-kta35d-MuiTypography-root {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans 3', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.css-1w74vsl {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.css-1xwioms {
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100vh - 64px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}

.glow-1 {
  width: 467px;
  height: 922px;
  margin-top: -241px;
  margin-left: -228px;
  border-radius: 303.5px;
  transform: rotate(65.71deg);
  filter: blur(148px);
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.21) 0%,
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.18) 100%
  );
}

.glow-2 {
  width: 414px;
  height: 734px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-left: 881px;
  border-radius: 233.5px;
  transform: rotate(-54.37deg);
  filter: blur(137px);
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.26) 0%, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.21) 100%
  );
}

.glow-3 {
  width: 467px;
  height: 1234px;
  margin-top: -195px;
  margin-left: 404px;
  border-radius: 233.5px;
  transform: rotate(-54.37deg);
  filter: blur(300px);
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.29) 0%, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.22) 100%
  );
}

@keyframes shimmerGlow {
  0% {
    background-position: top;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: bottom;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top;
  }
}

/*
  I want the glow to work as if it was absolute
    (IE: It should scroll with the container)

  But i want it to appear how fixed does
    (IE: Behind the toolbar and scrollbar)

*/

.glow-1,
.glow-2,
.glow-3 {
  position: absolute; /* change to absolute */
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: shimmerGlow 20s infinite linear;
  pointer-events: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  will-change: all;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: hsl(var(--foreground) /.2);
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 60px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: hsl(var(--card-foreground) /.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="app">
      <main>
        <div class="css-ohwg9z">
          <header class="css-4tfloy-MuiPaper-root-MuiAppBar-root">
            <div class="css-1oqqzyl-MuiContainer-root">
              <div class="css-r6ewbb-MuiToolbar-root">
                <div class="css-kta35d-MuiTypography-root">
                  Demo</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div style="padding-top: 64px;">
          </div>
          <div class="css-1xwioms">
            <div id="top-of-page" style="height: 1px;">
            </div>
            <div class="glow-1">
            </div>
            <div class="glow-2">
            </div>
            <div class="glow-3">
            </div>
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
            <span>4</span>
            <span>5</span>
            <span>6</span>
            <span>7</span>
            <span>8</span>
            <span>9</span>
            <span>10</span>
            <span>11</span>
            <span>12</span>
            <span>13</span>
            <span>14</span>
            <span>15</span>
            <span>16</span>
            <span>17</span>
            <span>18</span>
            <span>19</span>
            <span>20</span>
            <span>21</span>
            <span>22</span>
            <span>23</span>
            <span>24</span>
            <span>25</span>
            <span>26</span>
            <span>27</span>
            <span>28</span>
            <span>29</span>
            <span>30</span>
            <span>31</span>
            <span>32</span>
            <span>33</span>
            <span>34</span>
            <span>35</span>
            <span>36</span>
            <span>37</span>
            <span>38</span>
            <span>39</span>
            <span>40</span>
            <footer>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Fixed position which displays the effect how i would like, but no longer scrolling with the container:

https://jsfiddle.net/ugoa7y5t/

```css
:root {
    --gradient: linear-gradient(to top left, #e65c00, #F9D423);

    --background: 25 65% 3.6%;
    --foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --muted: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --muted-foreground: 25 10% 54.5%;

    --popover: 25 57% 6.30%;
    --popover-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --card: 25 57% 6.31%;
    --card-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --border: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --input: 25 0% 17.55%;

    --primary: 25 100% 45%;
    --primary-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --secondary: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --secondary-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --accent: 25 0% 17.55%;
    --accent-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
    --destructive-foreground: 25 10% 97.25%;

    --ring: 25 100% 45%;
  }

html,
body,
#root,
.app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans 3', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(var(--background));
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.css-ohwg9z {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.css-4tfloy-MuiPaper-root-MuiAppBar-root {
    background-color: hsla(25, 57%, 6.31%, 1);
    color: hsla(25, 10%, 97.25%, 1);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1100;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.css-1oqqzyl-MuiContainer-root {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .css-1oqqzyl-MuiContainer-root {
      padding-left: 24px;
      padding-right: 24px;
  }
}
.css-r6ewbb-MuiToolbar-root {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 56px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px){
  .css-r6ewbb-MuiToolbar-root {
      min-height: 64px;
  }
}

.css-kta35d-MuiTypography-root {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans 3', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.css-1w74vsl {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.css-1xwioms {
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100vh - 64px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}

.glow-1 {
  width: 467px;
  height: 922px;
  margin-top: -241px;
  margin-left: -228px;
  border-radius: 303.5px;
  transform: rotate(65.71deg);
  filter: blur(148px);
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.21) 0%,
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.18) 100%
  );
}

.glow-2 {
  width: 414px;
  height: 734px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-left: 881px;
  border-radius: 233.5px;
  transform: rotate(-54.37deg);
  filter: blur(137px);
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.26) 0%, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.21) 100%
  );
}

.glow-3 {
  width: 467px;
  height: 1234px;
  margin-top: -195px;
  margin-left: 404px;
  border-radius: 233.5px;
  transform: rotate(-54.37deg);
  filter: blur(300px);
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.29) 0%, 
    hsl(var(--primary) /0.22) 100%
  );
}

@keyframes shimmerGlow {
  0% {
    background-position: top;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: bottom;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top;
  }
}

/*
  I want the glow to work as if it was absolute
    (IE: It should scroll with the container)

  But i want it to appear how fixed does
    (IE: Behind the toolbar and scrollbar)

*/

.glow-1,
.glow-2,
.glow-3 {
  position: fixed; /* change to absolute */
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: shimmerGlow 20s infinite linear;
  pointer-events: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  will-change: all;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: hsl(var(--foreground) /.2);
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 60px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: hsl(var(--card-foreground) /.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="app">
      <main>
        <div class="css-ohwg9z">
          <header class="css-4tfloy-MuiPaper-root-MuiAppBar-root">
            <div class="css-1oqqzyl-MuiContainer-root">
              <div class="css-r6ewbb-MuiToolbar-root">
                <div class="css-kta35d-MuiTypography-root">
                  Demo</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div style="padding-top: 64px;">
          </div>
          <div class="css-1xwioms">
            <div id="top-of-page" style="height: 1px;">
            </div>
            <div class="glow-1">
            </div>
            <div class="glow-2">
            </div>
            <div class="glow-3">
            </div>
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
            <span>4</span>
            <span>5</span>
            <span>6</span>
            <span>7</span>
            <span>8</span>
            <span>9</span>
            <span>10</span>
            <span>11</span>
            <span>12</span>
            <span>13</span>
            <span>14</span>
            <span>15</span>
            <span>16</span>
            <span>17</span>
            <span>18</span>
            <span>19</span>
            <span>20</span>
            <span>21</span>
            <span>22</span>
            <span>23</span>
            <span>24</span>
            <span>25</span>
            <span>26</span>
            <span>27</span>
            <span>28</span>
            <span>29</span>
            <span>30</span>
            <span>31</span>
            <span>32</span>
            <span>33</span>
            <span>34</span>
            <span>35</span>
            <span>36</span>
            <span>37</span>
            <span>38</span>
            <span>39</span>
            <span>40</span>
            <footer>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Can you improve your question by using the [Snippet editor] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) instead ?

Comment: Updated, Thank you for sharing how to utilize the built-in code snippet. :-)